# I don't understand something in the example

Tags: c#

In Nemanja Boric's answer, I don't understand what the for loop is for because it only runs 1 instruction(e.g.arr[i].s_id = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());) at a time or something.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter StudentId, StudentName, 
    CourseName, Date-Of-Birth");

    arr[i].s_id = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    arr[i].s_name = Console.ReadLine();
    arr[i].c_name = Console.ReadLine();
    arr[i].s_dob = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: what you don't understand in the example?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and should be a comment.

Comment: ..needs another }

Answer (score 1):

The for loop will run everything inside the curly braces for each value of i, it runs ALL code inside the braces each loop, not just one line. The number four is arbitrary and repeats the code four times. It doesn't specifically have to be four.

Answer (score 0):

The loop will run 4 times and take four sets of student data. It will store in the array arr.

Each time the loop comes around it will wait for you to enter 4 lines of data. It will then prompt again with why writeline statement to enter the next students details.